# Duplicate storage over multiple disks

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

In Laravel it is possible to use multiple disks as storage providers.
What's a good practice to replicate/duplicate storage over multiple disks?

- Is it a good option to use a job to copy the contents of disk A to disk B?
- Is it better to save the new file(s) to disk A and disk B immediately?

Comment: Either?  Depends on your requirements, not sure how we're supposed to answer it for you. If you absolutely need them in both locations, do the latter, but since PHP is synchronous, that solution won't scale well unless you hand it off to a forked/background process.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer you're looking for, but the best practice is not to involve the application in the data redundancy / duplication.

This is something that should ideally be handled on the storage layer.